# change default options for movie in pdfpc

Tags: beamer, multimedia

As some of you know [pdfpc](https://pdfpc.github.io/) lets you to embed movies in beamer latex.
Thing is that the default options for movie are "autostart" and "loop".

```
% Package: textpos is required for textblock*
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
% fullFrameMovie
%
% Arguments:
%
%   [optional]: movie-options, seperated by &
%       Supported options: loop, start=N, end=N, autostart
%   Default: autostart&loop
%
%   1. Movie file
%   2. Poster image
%   3. Any text on the slide, or nothing (e.g. {})
%
% Example:
%   \fullFrameMovie[loop&autostart]{apollo17.avi}{apollo17.jpg}{\copyrightText{Apollo 17, NASA}}
%
\newcommand{\fullFrameMovie}[4][autostart&loop]
{
    {
        \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}


        % to make this work for both horizontally filled and vertically filled images, we create an absolutely
        % positioned textblock* that we force to be the width of the slide.
        % we then place it at (0,0), and then create a box inside of it to ensure that it's always 95% of the vertical
        % height of the frame.  Once we have created an absolutely positioned and sized box, it doesn't matter what
        % goes inside -- it will always be vertically and horizontally centered
        \frame[plain]
        {
            \begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(0\paperwidth,0\paperheight)
            \centering
            \vbox to 0.95\paperheight {
                \vfil{
                    \href{run:#2?autostart&#1}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=0.95\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{#3}}
                }
                \vfil
            }
            \end{textblock*}
            #4
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change this code to remove the autostart and the loop options, so I can play the movie with a single click and after it ends, play it again with another click?
The code comes from a sty file in a zip file from [here](https://pdfpc.github.io/demo/pdfpc-video-example.zip)

Ps  I could not find a single e-mail to contact the developers of pdfpc, that's why I am posting my question here.

Comment: github page have an issue tracker. Why don't you use media9 http://www.ctan.org/pkg/media9?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing is to get rid of the sty file and put the important commands in the tex file.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % don't use navigation tools
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos} %needed for textblock
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
{
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\begin{frame}[plain] 
  \begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(0\paperwidth,0\paperheight)
  \centering
  \vbox to 0.95\paperheight {
    \vfil{
    % Next command is the minimum needed. Everything else is just to keep it in the correct position.
    \href{run:apollo17.avi}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=0.95\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{apollo17.jpg}} 
         }
  \vfil  }  
  \end{textblock*}
\end{frame}
}  

\end{document}
```

The movie now starts when you click on it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the given `pdfpc-commands.sty` file is not conform to its specification. The line 35, reading:

```
\href{run:#2?autostart&#1}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=0.95\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{#3}}
```

should be:

```
\href{run:#2?#1}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=0.95\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{#3}}
```

(removing `autostart&`).

This way you get autostart and loop behavior by default (no option), and on-click behavior if you use an empty option field (`[]`), like this:

```
\fullFrameMovie[]{apollo17.avi}{apollo17.jpg}{\copyrightText{Apollo 17, NASA}}
```